# Aurora MySQL replication error when a trigger is created on the master instance

Tags: mysql, triggers, amazon-rds, replication

I have an Aurora cross region read replica set up in AWS. It all works perfect at the moment but when I create a trigger on the master instance it causes a replication error on the slave instance. The code for the trigger is below.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `mydb`.`user_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `user` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

END
```

The error I get is:

```
Error 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation' on query. Default database: 'mydb'. Query: 'CREATE DEFINER=`myuser`@`%` TRIGGER `mydb`.`user_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `user` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

END'
```

What's strange is that when I check the slave, the trigger is actually created. But because the error blocks up the replication I have to run the following to get it skip the error.

```
CALL mysql.rds_skip_repl_error;
```

I've tried setting `log_bin_trust_function_creators` to 1 but it doesn't seem to make any difference. When I run the following on the slave instance it says it's value is `ON`

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin_trust_function_creators';
```

Do I need to set that variable to 1 on the master instance as well?
Any help would be really appreciated. I've been Googling for hours but most of the stuff I find is talking about MySQL dumps which can have the definer removed but obviously that isn't possible in this case.